# Why can't I set up Airtag via my MacBook Pro M1 since it is able to run iPhone programs natively?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, airtag

The question is in the topic; the case is the following. I have several MacBooks and no iPhones at all - I just don't like them. I have a cat and I ordered an Airtag to follow him if he passes outside.

MacBook Pro M1s seem to run very similar hardware as iPhones; even native support for running applications is there. I wonder why I just couldn't **set up** the Airtag on a MacBook since exactly that device all the time reaches the Airtag. It seems to me like a ridiculous attempt from Apple to lock Airtag not even to "Apple trademark" but to make every Apple user to buy an iPhone and it's quite disappointing.

I would like to have any option to track my cat via MacBook M1, Mini M1, or Mac Studio. Does anyone know any way to do it? (as it seems, Xcode emulation for iPhones is quite limited and the application "Find My" for the iPhone version is hidden for macOS users). Maybe there is a hack that would allow installing the "Find My" application with the version from iPhone, not macOS?

I hope someone could manage to solve this puzzle since Apple blocked this post on their own discussion pages.

Answer (score 2):

Apple only permits Airtags to be [setup using an iPhone, iPad, or ipod](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210973).

You can't use any Mac to setup an Airtag at this time. In addition, because of how Airtags work, Apple also doesn't recommend using them to track pets.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've seen it in the documentation. The question was not about the current restrictions but about the explanation why they do not allow this and the means to override this restriction.

Comment: I understand but there is no way to override the restriction.

Comment: The only reason Apple don't recommend tracking a pet is for liability. Go for it if you want